# Overlay scenes/regions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on my first spritekit app and had a quick question on how to handle something I had in mind. I am working on a prototype of a board game I had in mind and wanted to do some brainstorming in an iOS Map.

The main scene is a world map that the user can pan around. I have this working at the moment. My next step is to create some overlay that would appear with a bunch of actions/cards available for the user to activate.

Do you guys have any tips on how to set this up? Would this overlay be another scene? I don't think that is correct since the SKView can only present 1 scene at a time. In addition, I currently have a UIPanGestureRecognizer, I would want this to stop working in the region my overlay is in.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you are looking for is a node's zPosition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an SKNode and add your actions/cards to that node. You can then add the node to your world map node (so it pans appropriately) as an overlay. You should set the zPosition of the overlay node to a value larger than your world map's zPosition so it appears over the map.